# While installing Django i am getting the following things instead of version name

Tags: django

(modelformsave) C:\Users\nikhi\OneDrive\Consultadd training\Django\modelformsave>pip freeze

asgiref @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/asgiref_1605055780383/work
certifi==2020.12.5
Django @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/django_1606860386887/work
psycopg2 @ file:///C:/ci/psycopg2_1608147681824/work
pytz @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pytz_1606604771399/work
sqlparse @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sqlparse_1602184451250/work
wincertstore==0.2

I am getting the following error while trying to see the version
Cannot find file file:///tmp/build/80754af9/asgiref_1605055780383/work

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are typing "pip freeze", which will give a list of all the python modules installed in your environment.
If what you want to do is seeing the Django version, then you need to run the following commands (without the double quotes):

```
"django-admin --version"
```

that should give you the Django version.